# To filter out input in lowercase characters

Tags: linux, filter

I need to filter out input in lowercase characters. I tried giving a file to the command:

```
cat ws2.txt | sed "s/[a-zA-Z0-9]/[A-Z]/g"
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  Please show some example input and output, i.e. given the input string "FooBar" should it print "ooar", "FB", "FOOBAR", "foobar", or what?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you're trying to convert lower to upper or remove lower all together. Give this a shot for the lower to upper conversion.

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:] < ws2.txt
```

To trim out lowercase chars you can use `sed`

```
sed -e 's/[a-z]//g' ws2.txt
```

Or you can use `tr` as suggested by @fd0

```
tr -d '[:lower:]' < ws2.txt
```

To trim out numbers and capital letters use (which now sounds like what you want).

```
tr -d '[A-Z0-9]' < ws2.txt
```

Comment: Please see the [useless use of cat award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: @SatoKatsura Good read, thank you. Updated my answer.

Comment: How about adding `tr -d [:lower:]  < ws2.tx` ?

Comment: @fd0 I like it. Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `perl` installed (use `which perl` and if it is installed the output should look something like `/usr/bin/perl`), you can do a perl one-liner and adjust the [regular expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm) to your liking.

```
perl -p -i.bak -w -e 's/[a-z]//g' test.txt            # strips lowercase
```

or

```
perl -p -i.bak -w -e 's/([a-z])/\U$1/g' test.txt     # converts to uppercase
```

The `-p` tells perl to write a program for you. The `-i` specifies to make a backup of the input file `test.txt` and name it `test.txt.bak`. The `-w` enables warnings (good in case you've erred or mis-typed something), and the `-e` says the following text is the code you wish to execute.